# Routing to one IP via different gateways

Tags: networking, routing, openvpn, subnet

I have an OpenVPN connection (point to point). When program connects to server it gets IP and Gateway dynamically, from server.

I need to make windows add route to my secure server through given gateway. For example open VPN gives IP: 192.168.100.2, gw: 192.168.100.1. My secure server's IP is 10.0.0.1, i need to make them connected. My router, he's also working as open vpn server (MIKROTIK) see both of them, i can connect them using command **route add 10.0.0.1 mask 255.255.255.255 192.168.1.1**, but openVPN can give different IP and gateway for different user. I want to make windows add route to DHCP specified gateway. Virtual adapter's interface number is 19, i've tried to add route like this: **route add 10.0.0.1 mask 255.255.255.255 0.0.0.0 metric 1 if 19**, but if i do route print after that it shows that my route has ~31 metric, that's more than metric for my internet connection, and it's impossilbe to reach this route.

sorry for long post, i don't know how to explain better (if i knew, i'd asked google).

p.s. as temporary solution i've made openvpn server give same ip and gateway for two users, but it's not a good solution.

UPD: User on windows 7 machine don't have administrator rights, so OpenVPN is unable to add routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best bet is to create an "on-connect" script that adds your routes as needed.  There is no way for you to create a "blanket-route" that would cover every possible IP in the subnet.

as far as how to construct your "on-connect" script... you can read another question that has been answered here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/28733/how-do-i-run-a-script-after-openvpn-has-connected-successfully

Comment: yes, i thinked of it, but the second problem i've forgot to mention is that - user, running openVPN client have limited rights, so openvpn don't have rights to add routes..

Comment: You may need to put the user openVPN is running as into the "Network Configuration Operators" group.  This should give the user enough rights to add/delete routes without being a full admin.